# PHP (PCLZIP) - Creating a zip file from array with URLs?

Tags: php, url, zip

The title pretty much speaks for itself, i have an array with URLs to images on another server, and i want to push them all down into a zip archive.

I'm getting the error:

```
Error: PCLZIP_ERR_MISSING_FILE (-4) : File '...url to image...' does not exist
```

Which seems to be incorrect since i can view the image in the browser if i copy the source. I tried changing it to a file on the same server, and that seems to work, so it must be because the files are on another server. Is it possible to bypass that somehow and make it work?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I assume you have blanked out `'...url to image...'` and you don't have that in the array?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to download the files to your server first before creating a zip file, whether it be temporarily or permanently. Download the files to your server, zip them up, then delete them!